# Get Attribute from Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need a method that can give me back the value of a specified attribute inside a specified xpath. So for example if we have `xpath = /root/foo/body/part[5]/test[3]` and we want the value of the attribute `id` inside the `test[3]` tag of the xpath then I need to be able to call a method that looks something like this:

```
public String getAttributeValue(String xpath, String attribute) {
     String attributeValue = "xpath/attribute".value();
     return attributeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
public String retrieveAttributeValue(Document document, String xpath, String attribute) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(xpath + "/" + attribute);
    String attributeValue = "" + xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
    return attributeValue;
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work ? I don't see the '@' command in your XPath statement.

Comment: Yes, you would have to pass the attribute, i.e. `@id`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the `@` command

```
//xpath[@attribute]
```

Note that you can also filter with the `@`

```
//xpath[@attribute='filtervalue']
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm guessing this would go with something like `XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();`? Could you possibly put it in a method so that I can see how it works altogether?

Comment: You can have a look at http://www.javabeat.net/2009/03/how-to-query-xml-using-xpath/ is a good tutorial and IIRC there's a clear sample of attribute extraction (using java XPath API)